# NTRU Key Exchange example implementation

Tags: math, public-key-encryption, public-key, ntruencrypt

Are there any open-source implementations of NTRU-KE (Preferably in Java or C#) out there that I can use as a reference for implementing it in a different language?

The implementations listed on the Wikipedia page for NTRUEncrypt don't have it included, and there's a paper covering the algorithm [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/718.pdf) but the language is a bit too technical for me to be able to understand it fully.

Answer (score 1):

#### Future readers, please prove me wrong (and post your own answer).

Given it is pretty new ([November 2013](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/718)) there probably aren't any implementations at all. Even the authors of the paper might not have implemented it themselves (you could ask them though). But as far as I can tell the protocol only uses operations that would have to be included in NTRUEncrypt implementations anyway. So it shouldn't be to difficult to write one yourself on top of an existing NTRU library. You can ask specific questions on the protocol here or on https://crypto.stackexchange.com. Probably you should try to understand the basics of NTRUEncrypt first, though.